# How to give radio input :checked with other onclick button?

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button

I have a problem that I cant solve which should be rather simple but just doenst work.
I have a button, which onclick should give an other input the attribute :checked.

My code and approach to this is:

The button:

```
<img src="../images/eye.svg" alt="eye"><a onclick="$('#active-button6').prop('checked', true);" href="#product__details">Bildgalerie</a>
```

So onclick it should select the input with the id #active-button6 and then set the prop checked to true. The href is just so it jumps to that area on the page.

The input just looks like a normal radio input:

```
<input class="acc-check" type="radio" name="accordion-1" id="acc-content-6"/>
```

Whats wrong with my approach? jQuery is linked in the head, so I didnt forget that.

Thanks alot in advance,
cheers

Comment: `#active-button6` <> `#acc-content-6`

Comment: oh wow, this is embarrassing.. thank you for not being as blind as me. sorry for that stupid question :D, works now fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have mistaken the ID of radio button.

It is `active-button6` but you use it like `#acc-content-6`.

Try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5t4uv32c/)

Comment: oh wow, this is embarrassing.. thank you for not being as blind as me. sorry for that stupid question :D, works now fine